# CakePHP HABTM find all records that have associated records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-model

I have a model - "Category" which HABTM "Blog".  I need to create a query that will only select categories that have more zero blogs associated with them.  I'm having trouble working out how to do this.  All I've come up with is getting the categories out of the database using find('all'...) and then extracting those that have something in the $category['Blog'] array.  Obviously I'd much prefer to not have to ask the database to do all that work, so a more elegant solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really elegant (short), but I think this is the correct way:

1. add a `blogs_category_count` field to categories table
2. add Category hasMany BLogsCategory with counterCache

so you just have to add a condition to that find('all')